# how to use setOnCheckedChangeListener in andrtoid studio java

Tags: android

I get error for this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton$OnCheckedChangeListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.xinyu.WaterValve.BluetoothFragment.onCreateView(BluetoothFragment.java:53)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bluetooth, container, false);

        switch_BT=(Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_bluetooth);
        txt2=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt2);
        textos=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textos);

        switch_BT.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

                if (switch_BT != null) {
                    switch_BT.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
                }

                if(b){
                    txt2.setText("show by");
                }
                else {
                    txt2.setText("");
                }
            }
```

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'void android.widget.Switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton$OnCheckedChangeListener)'
on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can safely remove following lines:

```
if(switch_BT != null){
    switch_BT.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
}
```

Because you already set the listener 4 lines before:

```
switch_BT.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (switch_BT != null)
{
 switch_BT.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
}
```

Above lines of code are creating the issue because you are setting setOnCheckedChangeListener under the same listener.